# Python looping questions

Tags: python, loops

```py
def up_to_keyword(items: list[str], keyword: str) -> list[str]:
    """Return a new list that contains only the items that occur before keyword
    in items, or all items if keyword is not an element of items.  Do not
    include keyword in your result.

    >>> up_to_keyword(['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], 'yellow')
    ['red', 'orange']
    >>> up_to_keyword(['some', 'body', 'once', 'told', 'me'], 'world')
    ['some', 'body', 'once', 'told', 'me']
    """
```

What is the return statement for this function?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
def up_to_keyword(items: list[str], keyword: str) -> list[str]:
    for index,item in enumerate(items):
        if item==keyword: #search keyword
            return items[:index] #return items before index
    return items
```

**Output**

```
>>> up_to_keyword(['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'], 'yellow')
    ['red', 'orange']
>>> up_to_keyword(['some', 'body', 'once', 'told', 'me'], 'world')
    ['some', 'body', 'once', 'told', 'me']
```

Comment: This will crash when `keyword` is not in `items`.

Comment: You now add the overhead of a redundant search with the `in` operator. You should either catch the exception that `list.index` raises or use the `list.find` method instead so you don't have to perform the same search twice.

Comment: Do `list` have `.find` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.takewhile` with the keyword's inequality method as the predicate:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def up_to_keyword(items, keyword):
    return list(takewhile(keyword.__ne__, items))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/RevolvingUnitedBlock